# unisharp laravel filemanager - can not browse images folder

Tags: javascript, laravel, tinymce

I am using unisharp laravel filemanager with tinymce editor. When i click on image, it does not take me to files directory window, all i see is my homepage header and footer and blank body. please see this screenshot
http://prnt.sc/ce8yam

I followed their installation guide in github.com/UniSharp

here is my view page

```js
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var editor_config = {
    path_absolute : "/",
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
      "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
      "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
      "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media",
    relative_urls: false,
    file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
      var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
      var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

      var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
      if (type == 'image') {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
      } else {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
      }

      tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        file : cmsURL,
        title : 'Filemanager',
        width : x * 0.8,
        height : y * 0.8,
        resizable : "yes",
        close_previous : "no"
      });
    }
  };

  tinymce.init(editor_config);
</script>
```

```html
<textarea name="content" class="form-control my-editor"></textarea>
```

and my config/lfm.php is exactely the same as it is shown in their github page

https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/blob/master/doc/config.md

Your help is highly appriciated. Thank you!

Comment: in lfm.php if you change middleware to  'middlewares'           => ['web', 'auth'], seems to work. I am using laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem as well, and it might be a code mistake

In `/vendor` => `/unisharp` => `/laravel-filemanager` => `/src` => `routes.php`

A route group is called:

```
Route::group(compact('middleware', 'prefix', 'as', 'namespace'), function () {
```

`dd($middlewares)` and the first array item is `[auth]`, which needs to be  `'\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser'`. This is the reason the file-manager links to the wrong url (because auth fails).

So if you change that line to the following, it will link to the correct url:

```
Route::group(array('middleware' => '\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middleware\MultiUser', 'prefix' => $prefix, 'as' => 'unisharp.lfm.'), function () {
```

Although **care, safety**! Make sure your route where you call the `laravel-manager` route is secured inside a group with `['middleware' => ['auth']` - in case you want the file manager only accessed by logged in users.

Answer (score 0):

did you include all assets in your html head?

```
<script src="/vendor/laravel-filemanager/js/lfm.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/laravel-filemanager/css/cropper.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/laravel-filemanager/css/lfm.css">
```